# Fixing Magento modules after applying SUPEE-6788 patch

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I have applied SUPEE-6788 to my Magento 1.7.0.2 and most of my extensions crashed. For some of them i could find updates that fixed the issue but for some i have to do it manually.

Now i am stuck at fixing Asperience_DeleteAllOrders

What i have done so far:
BEFORE:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <asperience_deleteallorders>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Asperience_DeleteAllOrders</module>
                <frontName>deleteallorders</frontName>
            </args>
        </asperience_deleteallorders>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

AFTER:

```
<admin>
<routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Asperience_DeleteAllOrders before="Mage_Adminhtml">Asperience_DeleteAllOrders_Adminhtml</Asperience_DeleteAllOrders>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
</routers>
</admin>
```

Also i have tried to rename the IndexController.php, change the class name inside and move it to a Adminhtml subfolder.

None of it works, i am still redirected to a 404 when i am trying to apply some of the functions.

Any hint is highly appreciated.